plurial of nouns ending with -ão
Nouns ending with -ão can have plurial in:

-ãos like Irmão -> Irmãos
-ães like Pão -> Pães
-ões like Coração -> Corações

Are there general rules to know which plural suffix to use for a noun other than learning by heart?

-oẽs is the default the others are exceptions i believe

We do have the same question asked right here but in Portuguese, with some good answers. Are you able to read them? Do they help you understanding plurals ending in -ão?

@gmauch You are right. It is in part a dupe. But my answer is clearer, perhaps...

@Lambie what strikes me as odd, is that your answer on this question is partially in Portuguese, so OP could also benefit from reading the other question I mentioned. Apart from that, It's unclear to me if two questions (and their accepted answers) asking basically the same question in Portuguese and English should be marked as duplicates. Perhaps should we ask it on meta?

@gmauch So what? This is a Portuguese site and we can use both languages. Not worth troubling with, in my view...(I  mean asking about this on Meta).


Muitos plurais
O plural das palavras que terminam em “-ão” certamente
está entre os grandes desafios para os falantes de Língua Portuguesa.
Isso porque existem três formas possíveis:
“-ãos”
“-ães”
“-ões”
A má notícia é que não existe uma regra universal que indique qual
terminação é a correta para cada palavra. É verdade que todos os
substantivos paroxítonos com essa terminação têm plural “-ãos”, mas são  regrinhas cheias de exceções. Na prática, vale mais a pena decorar as  palavras mais usadas.

The advice from this website is that you have to memorize them. The rules are full of exceptions. There are not tons of common ones. You will soon learn them.
Guia do estudante
